# When is France's next traffic light review? (Covid travel)

Tags: uk, france, covid-19

The UK is currently on [France's amber list](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage) for travel.

When is the next review date for France's traffic light list? (I could only find the UKs list online, the UK has recently moved France from amber plus to amber, but I want to know when France might move the UK from amber to green).

Comment: Given the fact that incidence is higher in the UK than in France and moving up, it is quite unlikely they will be downgraded anytime soon, and beyond that, we’re in crystal ball territory.

Comment: In Denmark, the ministry for foreign affairs monitors the situation and adjust their travel guidance lists whenever they see fit, they don't operate with a fixed schedule for updates. I guess the French authorities does something similar. And as @jcaron says, at the moment it's probably more likely that it will go the other way.

Comment: One final comment: the situation in the French West Indies is really dire and some indicators are deteriorating in the south of France. That seems to be the main focus right now and nothing in the government's communication suggests any plans to lift further restrictions.

Comment: I can't wait for when we all start speaking purely in euphemisms instead of using words to mean what they actually mean. Isn't this fun, yall? It's not "restrictions made by lawmakers who take advantage of the fear of Covid to increase their own power", it's "traffic lights"! And we're all 5 years old again!

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the British government, the French government has not publicized any schedule for reviews. The official reference for the list is the *[arrêté du 7 juin 2021 identifiant les zones de circulation de l'infection du virus SARS-CoV-2](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jorf/id/JORFTEXT000043618623)*. Legifrance lets you peruse all the different versions of the list and you will be able to see that's it's been modified almost weekly during June and July but not always on the same day of the week, with sometimes as little as 5 days or as many as 15 days between two versions.

There hasn't been any update in August and, given the general rhythm of activity within French government circles, it's entirely possible there won't be any before the end of the month. It's also late to hope for any significant effect on the summer tourism season so the pressure to relax restrictions is lower than it was earlier in the year (but additional restrictions could easily be added if the situation deteriorates).

All that to say that I wouldn't hold my breath for a quick change (and that's based solely on the political process, without even getting into any kind of speculation about the course of the pandemic in the UK).